# Telerik kendo-grid Paging - Taking too much time to load for the first time

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using Angular 6 and Telerik kendo-grid 4.8.4

Below is the sample code for the kendo-grid

```
<kendo-grid #grid="kendoGrid" class="k-grid-fullheight" (cellClick)="onCellClick($event)"
        (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)" [sortable]="{allowUnsort: false, mode: 'single'}"
        [sort]="state.sort" [filter]="state.filter" [data]="TestData" [selectable]="selectableSettings"
        [pageable]="true" [pageSize]="state.take" [skip]="state.skip" filterable="menu" [reorderable]="true"
        (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)" [groupable]="false" [group]="state.group" [columnMenu]="true"
        [resizable]="true">

<kendo-grid-column showSelectAll="true" [width]="60" [minResizableWidth]="60">
          <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
              <input type="checkbox" (click)="SetAllSelected($event)" />
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
              <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.selected" [attr.disabled]="dataItem.Name !== null  ? true : null" (click)=SetSelectedItem(dataItem) />
          </ng-template>
      </kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="Name" title={{NAME}} filter="text" [filterable]="true"
          headerClass="kendoColumn">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <a *ngIf="dataItem.Status === 0"
              [routerLink]="['/MyModule/details/'+dataItem.Id]">{{dataItem.Name}}</a>
            <span *ngIf="dataItem.Status === 1">{{dataItem.Name}}</span>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Trying to the follow the below link

[Server side parameters from kendo grid in angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520634/server-side-parameters-from-kendo-grid-in-angular-component)

Pagination works fine in the above link.

For the first time, the grid is taking 20 seconds to load because it is trying to fetch some 20,000 records.

How to modify the current kendo-grid to fetch only first 10 records?

On click of page number, can it be fetched from the Server again?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am using WebAPI method to get data from the Server Side. The only thing I need to do is how to fetch set of first or next records based on clicking of Page Number at the bottom of the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you post some ts code as well.

> How to modify the current kendo-grid to fetch only first 10 records?

Set `state.take` to `10` and `state.skip` to `0` and make the http call to fetch data.

> On click of page number, can it be fetched from the Server again?

Yes, in your `dataStateChange(event: DataStateChangeEvent)` in ts, you should attach `event` to `state` like `this.state = event;` and make the http call to retrieve the corresponding data (e.g. just `console.log(event)` and you will see that on page 3 `event.skip` will be 20, on page 4 `event.skip` will be 30, etc).